# Jquery selector to match href in a link ignore query

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some js on my site that links that contain STRING, it looks like this:

```
if($("a[href*='STRING']").length > 0){
    console.log("yes");
}
```

It returns true if there is a link like:

```
<a href="STRING.html">text</a>
```

The problem is it also returns true with a link like this:

```
<a href="index.html?search=STRING">text</a>
```

How can I limit the jquery selector to only look at the first part of the href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter()` and compare to the `pathname` property of the `<a>` which does not have the query string in it.

An `<a>` element has many properties similar to `window.location` like `host`, `search` , `protocol` etc.

The `pathname` starts after the domain host and ends before any `#` or `?`

```js
var $hasString= $('a').filter(function() {
  console.log(this.pathname)
  return this.pathname.includes("STRING");
}).css('color', 'red');

console.log("Matches:", $hasString.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="STRING.html">No search </a><br/><br/>
<a href="index.html?search=STRING">Search</a>
```

Comment: OK...I just added a length check and log you can use. Remove the `css()` from yours, it's only there as part of demo to show what it captures

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!

Comment: Oh that makes more sense to me now hold up let me try it out.